# How to import variables into different files in python

Tags: python

I am new to python scripting.

I have 3 files.

1. a.py
2. b.py
3. c.py

In the files:

- a.py : having all variables deceleration
- b.py : I am importing the a.py to use the variables declared in a.py like `import a`
- c.py: I need to use the initialized variables. i imported the a.py . but i am unable to use those defined variables.

can anyone tell me how to use the variables in c.py.

a.py: declaration

```
Variable_a = ' '
```

b.py:

```
import a
Variable_a = "value"
```

how to use the above `Variable_a` value in c.py.

Comment: this is the first time i am hearing of `declaring variables in python`

Comment: There might be a reason why you have such a setup, but it seems like what you want is a config file and read it using configparser.

Comment: This is a very strange thing to want to do. Can you explain what is your *actual* use case? Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: sorry
i am new to python script
that's why i used declaring keyword

my use case is:

i want to use a variable which is initialized in another file file

Comment: This sounds entirely like homework and should have been covered in a module scope lesson.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use `variable_a` in c.py,

```
from b import variable_a
print variable_a
```

or,

```
import b
print b.variable_a
#mention the variable as b.variable_a
```

Answer (score 0):

a.py

```
x=10
```

b.py

```
from a import x
print x
```

***UPDATED..***

a.py

```
x=10
y=20
z=30
```

b.py

```
import a
print a.x
print a.y
print a.z
```

Comment: here i have arround 30+ variables. How can i import each of them ?

Comment: You can use `from a import *`, but if you have 30+ such variables, you have a serious problem with your code. You would better describe what problem you want to solve and ask for a "pythonic" solution.

Comment: I am using SCONS. I need to set some environment variables for my project. Those variables i want to use in Sconstruct file.

Answer (score 0):

a.py

```
x = 10
```

b.py

```
import a
x = 110
```

c.py

```
import b

import b

x = 3
print "b.a.x",b.a.x
print "b.x  ",b.x
print 'x    ',x
```

Output of c.py

```
b.a.x 10
b.x   110
x     3
```

As you can see,
the values of the various variables is different.

Use the name that you need to use. Also, you can also use the `from .. import ..` statement if you wish to do so.

Answer (score 0):

When you import `a` and want to access `a` attributes you should write `a.attrName`.If you want to access `Variable_a` from `b` without `a.attrName` you should replace `import a` with `from a import Variable_a`
and in and so on.
see this example:

a.py

```
Variable_a = ' '
```

b.py

```
from a import Variable_a
Variable_a = "value"
```

c.py

```
from b import Variable_a
print Variable_a # Should print 'value'
```